# JSP/ DAO error : The method getInstance() is undefined for the type ConnectionPool

Tags: java, jsp, connection-pooling, dao

As you can see, this code is part of my Data Access Object Layer. 
I've never used the ConnectionPool Object before because i'm still studying Java.
Anyway, i'm getting an error message stating :

> The method getInstance() is undefined for the type ConnectionPool. 
>   (at line 5)

Should any of you have experienced this before, help would be appreciated.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool;

import music.business.*;

public class ProductDB
{
    //This method returns null if a product isn't found.
    public static Product selectProduct(String productCode)
    {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance(); //<===<====<====<=================
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM Product " +
                "WHERE ProductCode = ?";
        try
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, productCode);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next())
            {
                Product p = new Product();
                p.setCode(rs.getString("ProductCode"));
                p.setDescription(rs.getString("ProductDescription"));
                p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("ProductPrice"));
                return p;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
            DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
            pool.freeConnection(connection);
        }
    }
```

I just found out that i made a mistake:
- the ConnectionPool in my, above mentioned, class was not supposed to be Tomcat imported. Its a JNDI class. See below. The getInstance is actually a method in my JNDI class. Sorry for waisting your time guys. Thank you

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class ConnectionPool
{
    private static ConnectionPool pool = null;
    private static DataSource dataSource = null;

    public synchronized static ConnectionPool getInstance()
    {
        if (pool == null)
        {
            pool = new ConnectionPool();
        }
        return pool;
    }

    private ConnectionPool()
    {
        try
        {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/musicDB");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void freeConnection(Connection c)
    {
        try
        {
            c.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle)
        {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully someone with more experience comments on this, but I'm not sure you want to be creating a connection pool in your code like that.  The connection pool has a constructor to create a pool, but this will make a new instance of the pool and the idea behind connection pooling is to share one pool for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have Tomcat manage that pool for you.  It has instructions on how to create a JNDI data source.  You should do that and get this out of your code.

It'll have the added benefit of externalizing the connection parameters from your app. They'll live in configuration on the app server.

Answer (score 2):

A `ConnectionPool` can be created using its [constructor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.html#ConnectionPool%28org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration%29) which accepts some pool properties.  Even though this constructor is exposed creating a pool within your application, especially in each DAO may not be advisable.

The point of pooling is to have a single pool of connections that the application can retrieve a connection from when it needs to perform some work with the database.  Using this design the code will have multiple connection pools, which defeats the point of pooling.

Usually a datasource is established within Tomcat, which internally handles the building of a connection pool.  See these [resources](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) for more about connection pooling in Tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for you input. I may try to manage my pool of connections by using BoneCP.

Answer (score 1):

Create it in a 'DBService' class & share it, if you really don't want to define it in Tomcat. As Duffy says, defining it in Tomcat probably would be the best way..

For defining it in Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_(DBCP)_Configurations

The getInstance() syntax appears all wrong. For creating & configuring it directly, see: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html